# Why negative zero is triggering an error on insertion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've a schema defined in which the default value for some fields is zero. Then when doing an insertion via a form I have to negate those values, and some fields might not be present (so that it can be defaulted as zero).

This is the schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Acontecimiento', {
    campo : {type : String, required: true},
    titular: {type: String, required: true},
    fecha : {type : Date, default: Date.now, required: true},
    tipo : {type : String, required: true},
    brucelosis : {type : Number, default: 0},
    vacas : {type : Number, default: 0},
    toros : {type : Number, default: 0},
    novillitos : {type : Number, default: 0},
    vaquillonas : {type : Number, default: 0},
    terneras : {type : Number, default: 0},
    terneros : {type : Number, default: 0},
});
```

I don't know why but if for instance I put on every field a zero the insertion works, but if I leave some of them empty (so that it can be defaulted via mongoose schema) the error is being triggered.

Here it is my code:

```
   app.post('/api/acontecimiento', function(req, res) {
           if (req.body.tipo.a != undefined) {
             var insert = [
               {
                 campo : req.body.campo,
                 titular : req.body.titular,
                 fecha : req.body.fecha,
                 tipo : req.body.tipo.tipo,
                 brucelosis : - req.body.brucelosis,
                 vacas : - req.body.vacas,
                 toros : - req.body.toros,
                 novillitos : - req.body.novillitos,
                 vaquillonas : - req.body.vaquillonas,
                 terneras : - req.body.terneras,
                 terneros : - req.body.terneros
               },
               {
                 campo : req.body.tipo.a,
                 titular : req.body.titular,
                 fecha : req.body.fecha,
                 tipo : req.body.tipo.tipo,
                 brucelosis : req.body.brucelosis,
                 vacas : req.body.vacas,
                 toros : req.body.toros,
                 novillitos : req.body.novillitos,
                 vaquillonas : req.body.vaquillonas,
                 terneras : req.body.terneras,
                 terneros : req.body.terneros
               }
             ];
             Acontecimiento.create(insert, function(err, translado, transladado) {
               if (err) {
                     res.json({ success: false, message: 'Campo, titular, fecha y tipo de operacion deben especificarse'});
                  } else {
                    res.json({ success: true, message: 'Nueva operacion guardada'});
                  };
             });
           };
   });
```

PS. if I take out the negation everything works perfectly and the two insertions are being made even with some fields left empty. That is why I'm assuming there is a problem trying to negate the default value by schema

Comment: *"and some fields might not be present (so that it can be defaulted as zero)"* No it isn't, it's `undefined`, which is a completely different thing. Instead you should test for the presence of a property using [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) as in `if ( req.body.hashOwnProperty('vacas') {` before you attempt to access a property or similarly just iterate the keys in conversion. Also it's like that these are not numeric at all but "strings". This is the default for any POST body data present.

Comment: Hi Fjallbacka - can you show what error you are getting?

Comment: @NeilLunn yes, if the field is left empty as my schema has a default value then a zero will be assigned. And works perfectly for every use case but the one that I've specified here